# Scala vs Java, какой язык быстрее

Tags: java, scala

Какой язык быстрее java или scala, допустим есть две программы написанные по тому же алгоритму только одна написана на Java а другая на scala, какая программа сработает быстрее?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, так как он основаный на личных мнениях и порождает бесконечные дискуссии

Comment: А как скала может быть быстрее жавы, если и то, и другое компилируется в один и тот же байт код ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На такой вопрос полностью ответить нельзя, так как у каждого языка есть свои плюсы и минусы. Из википедии:

> Язык программирования компонентного ПО должен быть масштабируемым в
>   том смысле, что 
>   должна быть возможность с помощью одних и тех же концепций описать как
>   маленькие, так и большие части. Поэтому внимание было сконцентрировано
>   на механизмах абстракции, композиции и декомпозиции вместо введения
>   большого количества примитивов, которые могут быть полезными только на
>   каком-то одном уровне масштабирования.
>
> Масштабируемая поддержка компонентов может быть предоставлена языком
>   программирования, унифицирующим и обобщающим объектно-ориентированное
>   и функциональное программирование. Некоторые из основных технических
>   новшеств Scala — это концепции, представляющие собой сплав этих
>   парадигм программирования. В статически типизированных языках, к
>   которым относится Scala, эти парадигмы до сих пор были почти полностью
>   разделены.

Тут ничего не сказано про скорость, так что можно сделать вывод что Scala если не медленнее Java, то не быстрее во всяком случаи, так как Scala разработана на основе Java